# JNDI lookup from Applet to JBoss on EC2 instance

Tags: java, jboss, applet, amazon-ec2, jndi

I have JBoss 4.0.4.GA running on a Linux Amazon EC2 instance. I connect to a URL from my browser that maps to a JSP that downloads an Applet. The Applet code does a JNDI lookup for a Session Bean. The error I am seeing on my browser's Java console is:

```
Connection refused to host: 10.xxx.xxx.xxx
nested exception is: 
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
```

i.e. my applet is trying to connect to the *private* ip of the instance, which is doomed to fail of course.

The [abridged] code that does the JNDI lookup is:

```
System.setProperty(InitialContext.PROVIDER_URL, "jnp://<public ip of EC2 instance>:1099");
InitialContext ic = new InitialContext(null);
Object o = ic.lookup("ejb/....MySessionBean");
```

When I turn tracing on in the Java Console, I can see that a request is being made to port 1098 on the internal IP:

```
network: Connecting http://<public ip>:1099/ with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting http://<private ip>:1098/ with proxy=DIRECT
```

Can someone tell me how to get that 1098 communication to take place on the external IP?

Answer (score 1):

Adding -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=public-IP to JBoss startup solved this issue.